# Update webpage during async operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, user-experience

I'm consuming a web service asynchronously through its exposed `operationAsync` methods but I'm not really able to update my UI as intended...

```
protected async void DownloadInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Change text of status label to reflect work being done.
    DownloadStatus.Text = "Connecting to service...";

    using (var client = new Service.ServiceClient())
    {
        DownloadStatus.Text = "Getting data...";
        var response = client.DoOperation(args);

        // Handle the response in any way appropriate

        var control = new HtmlGenericControl();
        control.InnerHtml = response.Value;

        DownloadStatus.Text = "Operation complete.";
        // Write the response from the service to the page. (testing)
        ResultDiv.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

As those of you with more experience than me have already noticed, the `DownloadStatus` label text will never actually reflect an update until all of the work is done.

This doesn't really make for a good user experience so I need to find a different way.

One SO answer suggested making the button click synchronous, but have it call an asynchronous thread method. Sounds bizarre but the UI updates would then be done on the event handler while the async work is done somewhere else.

I also found [this question on ASP.NET](https://forums.asp.net/t/1828513.aspx?Async+thread+update+UI) who's answer builds a helper class to manage this sort of thing but I'm not really clear on how to define the progress messages here... Seems to me they're pretty much fixed as is for the example. I'd have to duplicate this code for every operation I want my application to perform which means a lot of bloat in my project.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the call to `operationAsync`? Does that code have any compilation warnings?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your asp.net code inside an UpdatePanel.

Read these tutorials to know how to use it properly: [Asp.net UpdatePanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) and [Introduction to UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

Here is a quick example on how it works:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <label runat="server" id="MyLabel">LabelInfo</label>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="MyLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeMyLabel_Click">Click me</asp:LinkButton>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void ChangeMyLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyUpdatePanel.Update();
   MyLabel.Text = "Woah I just changed at runtime!!";
}
```